# Simple mistake, postfix saving in a subfolder within user account?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I followed a guide for postfix (with postfix-mysql) and it works finally now, I had set up the user vmail to accept input but there is a bit of a problem, all my mail goes into this folder:

> /home/vmail/mysite.com/root/new/

instead of

> /home/vmail/new

As you can see the incorrect subfolder is 'mysite.com' and 'root' .. which means I probable messed something up along the line, can you think of any silly configurations that would do that? I wasn't sure postfix was allowed to make subfolders like that! Any any anything will be helpful to me.

Comment: Down-vote was incorrect; the question looks good to me. Although I don't know the answer. Back to zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postfix gets the path of the mailbox from a mysql query. You should check the fields returned to posfix by that query

Comment: Thank you a lot, I know the root of the problem now and can fix it. I had tried for days :)